# Prepend a prefix to all results from url_for, without making the prefix required by the routes

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, prefix

I am developing a Flask app running on a sub-route of a server.

Here's a minimal version of the app:

```py
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__, root_path="/test")
app.config["APPLICATION_ROOT"] = "/test"

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return url_for("index")

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return url_for("test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Here's the relevant part of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /test {
            return 302 /test/;
        }

        location /test/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, when I visit http://localhost/test/, the Flask application will get an incoming request at `/`, as proxied by nginx. This is configured at nginx level and cannot be changed, so what the application receives will always have the `/test` prefix truncated.

However I need `url_for` to generate URLs *with* that prefix. I am currently seeing `/index` at `/test/`, but what I expect is `/test/index`.

As shown in the code, `APPLICATION_ROOT` didn't work for me.

I have latest Flask (1.0.2) and dependencies.

Comment: See the duplicate, you need to use a `DispatcherMiddleware()` setup or put your routes in a blueprint.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I use either solution, my app will expect an actual URL of `//localhost/test/test/index` to trigger `app.route("/index")`, when it is currently `//localhost/test` (not expected to change). Nginx will truncate one `/test` and either the middleware or the blueprint will still expect another `/test` before the actual route.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can overload the decorator app.route, and not have to go to the wgsi serving your app, don 't know why that is the only answer accepted